# C# gRPC localhost - Error starting gRPC call: No such host is known

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to get Microsoft's gRPC "Greeter" application to work on my business laptop, but I keep getting the following exception when invoking the gRPC call:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Error starting gRPC call: No such host is known.")'
```

[This is the documentation from Microsoft, which I followed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
The exact code I'm running comes from Microsoft's samples and can be found [on their github here](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start/sample).

It literally boils down to starting the most basic gRPC server and then invoking the call via

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
var client =  new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
```

The call to SayHelloAsync is the one that throws the exception.
The exact same code on my home machine works fine.
I've already checked my /etc/hosts file for weird entries, but nothing.
I've also tried changing `https://localhost:5001` to `https://[::1]:5001` and `https://127.0.0.1:5001`, same exception, which I find incredibly weird.

I've also already tried http via `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);` and calling the http endpoint, same exception.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.
As expected it was a problem with the networking setup of my work laptop.

I had the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables set. These were picked up by the underlying HttpClient and tried routing the requests through the proxy. Removing the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables fixed the problem.
Alternatively setting the NO_PROXY environment variable to `localhost,127.0.0.1,::1` also fixed the problem.